# Publish/Subscribe simultaneously using MQTT

Tags: mqtt, publish, subscribe, simultaneous

I'm trying to make a code that can subscribe and publish operations simultaneously. I have this code below that I think should perform the functions simultaneously but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
#include <Adafruit_MQTT.h>
#include <Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h>
#include <Adafruit_MQTT_FONA.h>
//#include <stackThunk.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"

#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 13
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define Relay1            4
#define Relay2            0
#define Relay3            2
#define Relay4            14
//#define WLAN_SSID       "((DREAMNET03132490047))"             // Your SSID
//#define WLAN_PASS       "multan69"    
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

char str_hum[16];
char str_temp[16];
#define WLAN_SSID       "Connect(ow)03002618017"             // Your SSID
#define WLAN_PASS       "XXXXXXX"        // Your password

/************************* Adafruit.io Setup *********************************/

#define AIO_SERVER      "io.adafruit.com"
#define AIO_SERVERPORT  1883                   // use 8883 for SSL
#define AIO_USERNAME    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"            // Replace it with your username
#define AIO_KEY         "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"   // Replace with your Project Auth Key

/************ Global State (you don't need to change this!) ******************/

// Create an ESP8266 WiFiClient class to connect to the MQTT server.
WiFiClient client;
// or... use WiFiFlientSecure for SSL
//WiFiClientSecure client;

// Setup the MQTT client class by passing in the WiFi client and MQTT server and login details.
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);

/****************************** Feeds ***************************************/


// Setup a feed called 'onoff' for subscribing to changes.
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe Light1 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME"/feeds/Relay1"); // FeedName
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe Light2 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/Relay2");
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe Light3 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/Relay3");
Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe Light4 = Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/Relay4");
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish temp = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/Temperature");
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish hum = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/Humidity");




void MQTT_connect();

void setup() {


 Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  dht.begin();
  pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Relay4, OUTPUT);

  // Connect to WiFi access point.
  Serial.println(); Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);

  WiFi.begin(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  // Setup MQTT subscription for onoff feed.
  mqtt.subscribe(&Light1);
  mqtt.subscribe(&Light3);
  mqtt.subscribe(&Light2);
  mqtt.subscribe(&Light4);
}

void loop() {

  MQTT_connect();
   // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
      // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
      float h = dht.readHumidity();
      // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
      float t = dht.readTemperature();
      // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
      float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

      // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
      if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
      return;
      }

      // Compute heat index in Fahrenheit (the default)
      float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
      // Compute heat index in Celsius (isFahreheit = false)
      float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);
      Serial.print("Humidity: ");
      Serial.print(h);
      Serial.print(" %\t");
      Serial.print("Temperature: ");
      Serial.print(t);
      Serial.print(" *C ");
      Serial.print(f);
      Serial.print(" *F\t");
      Serial.print("Heat index: ");
      Serial.print(hic);
      Serial.print(" *C ");
      Serial.print(hif);
      Serial.println(" *F");


      Serial.print("Temperature in Celsius:");
      Serial.println(String(t).c_str());

      Serial.print("Temperature in Fahrenheit:");
      Serial.println(String(f).c_str());

      Serial.print("Humidity:");
      Serial.println(String(h).c_str());


    //dtostrf(gps_latitude, 4, 2, str_temp);
    //dtostrf(gps_longitude, 4, 2, str_hum);

  // Now we can publish stuff!
  Serial.print(F("\nSending Humidity value: "));
  Serial.print(String(h).c_str());
  Serial.print("...");
  if (! hum.publish(String(h).c_str())) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }
delay(1000);
  Serial.print(F("\nSending Temperature value: "));
  Serial.print(String(t).c_str());
  Serial.print("...");
  if (! temp.publish(String(t).c_str())) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed"));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("OK!"));
  }

//temperature_work();
  Adafruit_MQTT_Subscribe *subscription;
  while ((subscription = mqtt.readSubscription(20000))) {
    if (subscription == &Light1) {
      Serial.print(F("Got: "));
      Serial.println((char *)Light1.lastread);
      int Light1_State = atoi((char *)Light1.lastread);
    digitalWrite(Relay1, Light1_State);

    }
    if (subscription == &Light2) {
      Serial.print(F("Got: "));
      Serial.println((char *)Light2.lastread);
      int Light2_State = atoi((char *)Light2.lastread);
      digitalWrite(Relay2, Light2_State);
    }
    if (subscription == &Light3) {
      Serial.print(F("Got: "));
      Serial.println((char *)Light3.lastread);
      int Light3_State = atoi((char *)Light3.lastread);
      digitalWrite(Relay3, Light3_State);
    }
    if (subscription == &Light4) {
      Serial.print(F("Got: "));
      Serial.println((char *)Light4.lastread);
      int Light4_State = atoi((char *)Light4.lastread);
      digitalWrite(Relay4, Light4_State);

    }
  }


}

void MQTT_connect() {
  int8_t ret;

  // Stop if already connected.
  if (mqtt.connected()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT... ");

  uint8_t retries = 3;

  while ((ret = mqtt.connect()) != 0) { // connect will return 0 for connected
    Serial.println(mqtt.connectErrorString(ret));
    Serial.println("Retrying MQTT connection in 5 seconds...");
    mqtt.disconnect();
    delay(5000);  // wait 5 seconds
    retries--;
    if (retries == 0) {
      // basically die and wait for WDT to reset me
      while (1);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("MQTT Connected!");

}
void temperature_work(){
   delay(2000);


  }
```

However, when I upload the code of publish and subscription separately, it works fine. Can anyone please take a look at my code attempt and tell me what I'm doing wrong?